# THREE.js smooth material color cycle in separate geometries

Tags: javascript, three.js, cycle

guys!

Look at the codepen provided. Multiple curves animation. 
So i'm trying to reach this smooth hue change at every drawn curve.
The color of every next curve should be shifted in hue a bit.
And i need to control the duration of this shifting.
Right now the colors shift seem random and i cant control it's duration.

Need your help. Thanks.

```
'use strict';
var camera, scene, renderer, controls;
var params = {P0x: 0, P0y: 0,P1x: 0.6, P1y: 1.7,P2x: -0.1, P2y: 1.1,P3x: 0, P3y: 3,steps: 30};
var controlPoints = [[params.P0x, params.P0y, 0],[params.P1x, params.P1y, 0],[params.P2x, params.P2y, 0],[params.P3x, params.P3y, 0]];
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xd9e2ec, linewidth: 1 } );
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe:true,color: 0x4a4a4a, side: THREE.DoubleSide, opacity:0, transparent:true});
var angle1 = 0;
var angle2 = 0;
var color = 0;
var initialCurvesCount = 5;
var initialGroupsCount = 6;
var curveQuality = 500;
var hColor = 1;

var mesh = {};
var axis1 = new THREE.Vector3(0,0.8,1.2);
var axis2 = new THREE.Vector3(0,-0.8,3.2);
var geom = {};

var curveGeometry;
var curves;

var group = {};

var triangle = [[ 0, 0.5, -0.5, 0 ], [ 0.6, -0.5, -0.5, 0.6 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]];


init();
createCurveGroups();
createHelpers();
animate();

function createHelpers() {

  // var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( 4, 8, 0xadd6e8, 0xdddddd );
  // var gridHelper2 = new THREE.GridHelper( 4, 8, 0xadd6e8, 0xdddddd );
  // gridHelper2.rotation.x = 1.58;
  // gridHelper.position.y = 0;
  // gridHelper.position.x = 0;
  //
  // var axisHelper = new THREE.AxisHelper( 1 );
  // axisHelper.position.y = 0;
  // axisHelper.position.x = 0;
  //
  // scene.add( gridHelper );
  // scene.add( gridHelper2 );
  // scene.add( axisHelper );

}

function init() {

      scene = new THREE.Scene();
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);
      camera.position.set(-0,0,2);
      camera.rotation.y = -0;
      camera.frustumCulled = false;
      controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
      controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
      renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 1 );
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function createBezierCurveNEW(cpList, steps) {

  var N = Math.round(steps)+1 || 20;
  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  var curve = new THREE.CubicBezierCurve3();
  var cp = cpList[0];
  curve.v0 = new THREE.Vector3(cp[0], cp[1], cp[2]);
  cp = cpList[1];
  curve.v1 = new THREE.Vector3(cp[0], cp[1], cp[2]);
  cp = cpList[2];
  curve.v2 = new THREE.Vector3(cp[0], cp[1], cp[2]);
  cp = cpList[3];
  curve.v3 = new THREE.Vector3(cp[0], cp[1], cp[2]);
  var j, stepSize = 1/(N-1);
  for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      geometry.vertices.push( curve.getPoint(j * stepSize) );
  }
  return geometry;
};

function createTriangle(number) {
  geom[number] = new THREE.Geometry();
  geom[number].vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0.35, 0));
  geom[number].vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.35, -0.35, 0));
  geom[number].vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-0.35,-0.35, 0));
  geom[number].faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));
  geom[number].applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( 0, 0, 0 ) );
  mesh[number] = new THREE.Mesh(geom[number], mat);
};

function createCurveGroups() {
  for ( var i = 1; i <= initialGroupsCount; ++i ) {
  group[i] = new THREE.Group();
  scene.add( group[i] );
  group[i].rotation.set( 0, 3.15, i/((initialGroupsCount/6 - initialGroupsCount/130)) );
};
};
function cloneCurvesToGroups() {
for ( var i = 1; i <= (Object.keys(group).length); ++i ) {
var curvesArray = {};
curvesArray[i] = curves.clone();
group[i].add(curvesArray[i]);
}
};

function colorChanger() {
}

function morphTriangle() {

      group[1].add( mesh[1] );
      mesh[1].rotateOnAxis(axis1,(angle2 + 1));
      mesh[1].updateMatrix();
      mesh[1].geometry.applyMatrix( mesh[1].matrix );
      mesh[1].matrix.identity();
      mesh[1].position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
      mesh[1].geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

      group[1].add( mesh[2] );
      mesh[2].rotateOnAxis(axis2,-angle2);
      mesh[2].updateMatrix();
      mesh[2].geometry.applyMatrix( mesh[2].matrix );
      mesh[2].matrix.identity();
      mesh[2].position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
      mesh[2].geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

};

  function changeCreatedCurves() {
    angle1 += 0.00450;
    angle2 += 0.0020;
    createTriangle(1);
    createTriangle(2);
    morphTriangle();

  for ( var i = 1; i <= initialCurvesCount; ++i ) {

      controlPoints[0][0] = -0.09 ;
      controlPoints[0][1] = 0;
      controlPoints[0][2] = -0.035 + i/10000; //optional + Math.sin(angle1)/6;
      controlPoints[2][0] = mesh[2].geometry.vertices[0]['x'] + 0.1 - i/55  + Math.cos(angle1)/6;
      controlPoints[2][1] = mesh[2].geometry.vertices[0]['y'];
      controlPoints[2][2] = mesh[2].geometry.vertices[0]['z'] + i/20 + Math.sin(angle1)/6;
      controlPoints[1][0] = mesh[1].geometry.vertices[0]['x'] - i/20 + Math.sin(angle1)/6;
      controlPoints[1][1] = mesh[1].geometry.vertices[0]['y'];
      controlPoints[1][2] = mesh[1].geometry.vertices[0]['z'] - i/20 + Math.sin(angle1)/6;
      controlPoints[3][0] = triangle[0][0] - 0.05 + i/10;
      controlPoints[3][1] = triangle[1][0] - 0.05 + i/10;
      controlPoints[3][2] = triangle[2][0];


// !!! HERE IS THE PROBLEM !!!
      hColor = hColor + i*0.3;
     var wow = String("hsl(" + hColor*i + "," + 100 + "%" + "," + 70 + "%" + ")");
      //  console.log(wow)
      //  console.log("this is i "+ i);
      material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: wow, linewidth: 1 } );
// !!! HERE IS THE PROBLEM !!!
      curveGeometry = createBezierCurveNEW(controlPoints, (curveQuality/initialGroupsCount));
      curves = new THREE.Line(curveGeometry, material);
      group[1].add(curves);
      // debugger
      render();

      cloneCurvesToGroups();

    }
  };

  function disposeCurveGeometry() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= group[1].children.length; ++i) {
    group[1].children[0].geometry.dispose();
    group[1].children[0].material.dispose();
    for (var j = 1; j <= (Object.keys(group).length); ++j) {
    group[j].remove(group[j].children[0]);
    };
  };
  };

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  changeCreatedCurves();
  disposeCurveGeometry();
  onWindowResize();
};
```

[Working example code at codepen](http://codepen.io/yyynnn/pen/oBOBro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
var vueDifference = 20;
var speed = 0.03;
hColor = hColor + speed;

var wow = String("hsl(" + (hColor + i * vueDifference) + "," + 100 + "%" + "," + 70 + "%" + ")");
```